# Super conic sections?

Tags: polynomials, conic-sections, cubics, geometry

I know graphs of the form $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 + D x + E y + F = 0$ are conic sections, in that they are all cross sections of a cone. But what would happen if I changed the degree of the polynomial to 3? Would these be cross sections of a new 3D shape or a 4D shape? If it is possible, please provide a picture or some sort of representation of this shape thanks.

**EDIT**: Just to make it clear when I ask about the shape I mean the conic section, *not* the graph itself.

Comment: what happens is we know not so much up there.

Comment: They are not conics anymore. We can manipulate A,B,C values with sliders in Mathematica and see ContourPlots.

Comment: Notice, there is a picture of a cubic curve in the linked article. Also, I do think many curves in the plane can be obtained by intersecting surfaces in 3D, that would be the generic analog of planes intersecting a cone. Not too exciting, but that's my initial thought on your query.

Comment: Yeah I have wondered about this too...  But a polynomial of degree three is still a polynomial of degree three.  I think to get 3D conics there needs to be a third variable.

Answer (score 3):

I read the question again. I realize now the implicit mistake. Generically, provided $F$ is reasonably differentiable, any equation of the form $F(x,y) = 0$ gives a **curve** in the plane. If you change the exponent to say $Ax^3+\cdots +C=0$ then you would still have a curve in the plane. I suppose the question you are really asking: is such a curve interesting in some way which is similar to that of conic sections? I personally am aware of no such results, but, then again, I have not studied classical algebraic geometry in any depth. I can tell you this, the study of eliptic curves concerns the locus of points which satisfies a relatively simple cubic equation. The structure present there is in fact deeply interesting, there is a hidden group structure and apparently some way to take encryption beyond the current technique. See [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve)

So, all of that for just one cubic curve. I think the heart of your question is worthwhile and I hope someone eventually counters this one with a general theory of cubics. I would be happy to see it.

Comment: If your interested I made a graph of the figure [all elliptic curves with b = 0 pass through](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4f6klqpt7y). (May not be the simplest)

Comment: @tox123 Interesting, I have not managed to get the 3D stuff in Desmos to look that nice. Good work.

Comment: I didn't do all myself to be fair. I found a [pre-made graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nqom2ih05g) on google. I can't figure out who he/she is though

Comment: I found the 4D shape of elliptic curves (may not be the simplest possible). Imagine flat plane. Now imagine at a edge of the plane a prolate ellipsoid is rising out of it with the base facing you. It eventually becomes so big it is almost a open cylinder. This would be its cross section, please keep in mind I could be horribly wrong

Comment: Curious, you might try asking some questions about your construction once you have something a bit more precise. You might find interest.